# Git checkout branch or tag from multiple remotes

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I have a parameter passed down from an upstream build, lets say `$GIT_BRANCH`.

It's value can represent a git tag or git branch. I also have a `$GIT_REMOTE` passed down which allows me compute the source of my fetch and checkout path.

Always assume I run this before any of the following comments.

`git fetch $GIT_REMOTE --tags`

If $GIT_BRANCH was really a branch then its super simple `git checkout remotes/$GIT_REMOTE/$GIT_BRANCH`. Given the remote already exists.

If $GIT_BRANCH represented a tag you would be faced with the following error:

`error: pathspec 'remotes/origin/1.1.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Investigating refspec will tell you there is no such thing as a "remote tag" refs/tags only.

This means if I were somehow able to tell whether or not the `$GIT_BRANCH` was a tag or branch i could orientate the cmd properly to simply become.

`git checkout tags/$GIT_BRANCH`

Anybody able to build on this? Suggest an alternative? Or even suggest a way to reliably do this based on my suggestion? I have some concerns on branch_names that clash with tag names which might introduce some edge cases.

Comment: The most straightforward way, though it kind of pollutes the upper test-build layer a little bit, would be to have it pass down the full string `refs/remotes/origin/branch` or `refs/tags/v1.1.0` or whatever. A full reference name *is* a branch, tag, or remote-tracking branch if it starts with `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, or `refs/remotes/` respectively. If your remote names avoid `/` then a name starting with `refs/remotes/X/*` is a remote-tracking branch name for remote X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
git fetch origin --tags
if git show-ref -q --verify "refs/tags/$GIT_BRANCH" 2>/dev/null; then
    git checkout refs/tags/$GIT_BRANCH
else
    git checkout remotes/$GIT_REMOTE/$GIT_BRANCH 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For branch you can use `git checkout remotes/$GIT_REMOTE/$GIT_BRANCH` or `git checkout $GIT_REMOTE/$GIT_BRANCH`.

But for tags, you should use **`git checkout $GIT_BRANCH`** directly. Since you have already use `git fetch $GIT_REMOTE --tags` to fetch tags locally in `.git/refs/tags`, so you can checkout them directly.

You can use shell script to detect if the parameter `$GIT_BRANCH` is branch or not:

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ `git branch | grep $GIT_BRANCH` ]
then
    echo "it's branch"
else
    echo "it's tag"
fi
```

Comment: This would work, but i'll show my actual solution in the end.